# How do I have selenium get oauth access tokens from a web app?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, rest, oauth-2.0, python-requests

This is completely maddening... I have OAuth2.0 requests going to a [web app](https://zinfandel-api.centrastage.net/auth/oauth/token) and I want to retrieve my access token using python selenium.

I've tried using [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth), [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and [oauthlib.oath2](https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/clients/baseclient.html) to get an access token after [generating my api keys](https://rmm.datto.com/help/en/Content/2SETUP/APIv2.htm#). Selenium is the only path where I've see any results so I may be missing the target all together.

Only the kicker is this...

1. I can't see the browser handle.
2. I don't know any of the xpath elements.
3. I can't see any of the HTML from the popup in Chrome Developer tools.

The Datto [API Documentation](https://rmm.datto.com/help/en/Content/2SETUP/APIv2.htm) says to use [Postman](https://rmm.datto.com/help/en/Content/2SETUP/APIv2.htm#) to get your Access Token token. Which, I can do and make API calls form python, but this isn't a very repeatable process.

All of the [examples](https://rmm.datto.com/help/en/Content/2SETUP/APIv2.htm#) from Datto are adopting this process as well.

How do I using either selenium or a python script to simply perform oauth retrieve my access token so that I can variablize it in future requests?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
import time

#Oauth2.0 credentials.
client_id = 'public-client'
client_secret = 'public'

# URLs to retrieve tokens
authorize_url = "https://zinfandel-api.centrastage.net/auth/oauth/authorize"
access_token_url = "https://zinfandel-api.centrastage.net/auth/oauth/token"

# This is your API Public Key.
auth_user = 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE'

# This is your API Secret Key.
auth_pass = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE'

# This installs the driver that selenium needs to open your browser.
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

#browser.maximize_window()

time.sleep(3)

# This goes to a website.
browser.get(access_token_url)

# Used to download page source code
with open("page_source.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(browser.page_source)
    f.close()

time.sleep(5)

# A list of all window handles
main_window_handle = browser.window_handles

# Handle of the first window open.
main_window = main_window_handle[0]

# This will switch us to a new window if there is more than one.
# Right now the web app isn't being seen as a window.
for handle in browser.window_handles:
    if handle != main_window:
        popup = handle
        #print(popup)
        browser.switch_to.window(popup)

time.sleep(3)

print("Starting anonymous key send.")

actions = ActionChains(browser)

time.sleep(3)

popup_alert = Alert(browser)

print(popup_alert.page_source)


# This will error out because the page isn't an alert.
#browser.switch_to.alert

# Is this an Alert?
#with open("active_elment_alert.html", "w") as f:
#    f.write(browser.page_source)
#    f.close()

# I'm going to try to switch to a frame and write to it.
browser.switch_to.frame

# If this is a frame we'll see soething here.
with open("active_elment_frame.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(browser.page_source)
    f.close()


browser.switch_to.active_element

# Used to download active element source code.
# You can see that after I switch I don't see any html other than what was presented earlier.
with open("active_elment_source.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(browser.page_source)
    f.close()

################## I THINK THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP ##################
#This is probably just posting nonsense in the empty html body.

# I'm trying to xpath to either a label or anything with the username field.
mystery_field = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(),ernam)]')
#mystery_field = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//label[contains(text(),ernam)]")

print(mystery_field.text)

#start_a_doing_stuff = browser.switch_to.frame(mystery_field)

time.sleep(3)

actions.click(mystery_field).perform

time.sleep(3)

actions.send_keys(client_id).perform()

time.sleep(3)

actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()

time.sleep(3)

actions.send_keys(client_secret).perform()

time.sleep(3)

actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()

time.sleep(3)

print("The anonymous key send is done.")

time.sleep(3)

################## I THINK THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP ##################

# This portion appropriately sends content to authorize url.

#user_name_field = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
#password_field = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "password")

#user_name_field.send_keys(auth_user)

#user_name_field.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

#password_field.send_keys(auth_pass)

#password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#actions.perform()

#time.sleep(3)

#When everything is done, this closes your browser.
browser.quit()
```

When the script runs you can see the cursor in the username field, and when you go to the site the html body is empty.

But, without being able to see any of the fields I'm trying to send keys to the cursor as soon as the auth alert box opens.

I know that selenium doesn't see it as an [alert](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-alert-prompts-in-selenium-python/) because when I try to send keys to an alert element my code errors out.